# Custom shortcut for special character - Word 2016 Mac

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Good evening!

I am trying to find a way to assign a custom shortcut (for example control + s) for special characters found in the Latin section of Emoji & Symbols tab on Word 2016 Mac (for example ț).

On Windows its a rather trivial task - you can simply find it in the Insert - Symbols tab. Not so easy on Mac...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard - Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar

[image]

Which adds this icon to the menu bar, on the right...

[image]

Clicking that & selecting Show Character Viewer gives you access to any glyph you could imagine, including the entire Unicode suite...

[image]

Double-click a character to insert at the caret.

The Character viewer remembers its settings individually for every app you use it in, except Frequently Used, which is global.